# How to localize ASP.NET MVC + Spark application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, globalization, spark-view-engine

I'm using the Spark view engine, and want to localize the website. The methods described for 'conventional' MVC view engine do not work. Has anyone done this already? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [spark release package](http://sparkviewengine.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24940#DownloadId=62392) includes some sample projects, and one of them is called "Internationalization". I haven't had a look myself yet since I am just getting started with Spark, but it seems to be what you are looking for.